# Blackberry Seek Bar

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I have created one play button using ButtonField on blackberry screen, if I click on the button , I am able to play my audio files.

My requirement is  to create volume control seek bar (if we drag the seek bar we should be able to increase or decrease the volume) and play/pause button on blackberry screen (the play/pause button should be placed beside the seek bar)

Here is my code:

```
     HorizontalFieldManager hfmSecond = new HorizontalFieldManager();

        slider = new SliderField(
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_thumb_normal.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_progress_normal.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_base_normal.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_thumb_focused.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_progress_focused.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_base_focused.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_thumb_pressed.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_progress_pressed.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_base_pressed.png"),
            50, 0, 10, 10, FOCUSABLE );
        slider.setPadding( 5, 5, 5, 35 );
        slider.setBackground( BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground( 0xD3D3D3 ) );
        hfmSecond.add(slider);
        hfmSecond.add(_startPlayingButton);
        add(hfmSecond);
```

If I use above code, I am able to display one slide bar on my screen.

I am not able to display the button and also, I want to display the slide bar at the bottom of the screen with play/pause button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding the button at bottom of your screen use

```
hfmSecond.add(playButton);
hfmSecond.add(slider);
hfmSecond.add(pauseButton);
setStatus(hfmSecond);// this line will add your Hfm at bottom....
```

the above code will add playbutton then the slider and after that there would be a pause button and all of that are at bottom of the screen. I think your slider taking all the width so you are unable to see the button you have added in you `HorizontalFieldManager` so reduce the width of the slider will work for you.

Comment: you are setting the padding to slider so i guess it would be leaving some space to the left is it ?? Please resize the image you are using in your slider.

Comment: that's mean you are adding the hfmn before setting the status  so delete that line ... just use `setStatus(yourManagerObject);`

Comment: i didn't get what you try to say?

Comment: okk add the button and seekbar in your horizontalFieldManager and setStatus that horizontalFieldManager no need to add the hfm like add(horizontalFieldManager)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16290/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-ragi-and-bbdev)

Comment: hi,i have reduced my slider images height and width  and tested my app,it is throwing illegal argument Exception,if an image has height and width of 26*24,i have reduced to 13*12?then i am facing the exception and not able to display play/pause button?

Comment: i have referred the example from this url https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/test

Comment: can you check once ,UIExampleSlider Screen class example

Comment: come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-iphone-and-java